# Using glob to find all zip files recursively in three sub folder

Tags: python, python-3.x, glob

I am trying to look only in three specific subfolders and then recursively create a list of all zip files within the folders. I can easily do this with just 1 folder and recursively look through all subfolders that are within the inputpath, but there are other folders that get created that we cannot use plus we do not know what the folder names will be. So This is where I am at and I am not sure how to pass three subfolders to glob correctly.

```
# using  glob, create a list of all the zip files in specified sub directories COMM, NMR, and NMH inside of input_path
    zip_file = glob.glob(os.path.join(inputpath, "/comm/*.zip,/nmr/*.zip,/nmh/*.zip"), recursive=True)
    #print(zip_file)
    print(f"Found {len(zip_file)} zip files")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The string with commas in it is ... just a string. If you want to perform three globs, you need something like

```
zip_file = []
for dir in {"comm", "nmr", "nmh"}:
    zip_file.extend(glob.glob(os.path.join(inputpath, dir, "*.zip"), recursive=True)
```

As noted by @Barmar in comments, if you want to look for zip files anywhere within these folders, the pattern needs to be `...(os.path.join(inputpath, dir, "**/*.zip")`. If not, perhaps edit your question to provide an example of the structure you want to traverse.

Comment: Also need `/**/` in the path for `recursive=True` to work.

Comment: I was sort of hoping `inputpath` would contain that part but we are obviously just guessing here.

Comment: That wouldn't work. It has to be `comm/**/*.zip` to recurse into the `comm` folder.